# How to solve webpack plugin compilation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin

I am in the process of migrating my node.js project. I just upgraded to Webpack 4 and I can't compile the project after running `npm run dev`. It throws the following error:

```
Error: Plugin could not be registered at 'html-webpack-plugin-after-emit'. Hoo  k was not found.
  BREAKING CHANGE: There need to exist a hook at 'this.hooks'. To create a compa  tibility layer for this hook, hook into 'this._pluginCompat'.
```

```
  - Tapable.js:69 Compilation.plugin
    [treetopmall]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:69:9

  - util.js:89 Compilation.deprecated [as plugin]
    internal/util.js:89:15

  - dev-server.js:40 
    C:/Users/duncan/projects/treetopmall/build/dev-server.js:40:15


  - Hook.js:154 SyncHook.lazyCompileHook
    [treetopmall]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compiler.js:631 Compiler.newCompilation
    [treetopmall]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:631:26

  - Compiler.js:667 
    [treetopmall]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:667:29


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [treetopmall]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compiler.js:662 Compiler.compile
    [treetopmall]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:662:28

  - Compiler.js:328 Compiler.runAsChild
    [treetopmall]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:328:8

  - child-compiler.js:110 
    [treetopmall]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:110:21

  - new Promise

  - child-compiler.js:109 HtmlWebpackChildCompiler.compileTemplates
    [treetopmall]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:109:31

  - cached-child-compiler.js:344 PersistentChildCompilerSingletonPlugin.compileE    ntries
    [treetopmall]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/cached-child-compiler.js:344:21

  - cached-child-compiler.js:211 
    [treetopmall]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/cached-child-compiler.js:211:47
```

My package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.8.3",
    "apexcharts": "^3.19.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.14.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.3",
    "vue-awesome": "^4.0.2",
    "vue-chat-scroll": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-star-rating": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chalk": "^4.0.0",
    "chromedriver": "^83.0.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "cross-spawn": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.4",
    "inject-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.9",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-webpack": "^4.0.2",
    "mocha": "^7.1.2",
    "nightwatch": "^1.3.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "opn": "^6.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "ora": "^4.0.4",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "selenium-server": "^3.141.59",
    "semver": "^7.3.2",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.5.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "uglify-es": "^3.3.10",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
```

So as you can see, running `npm run dev` executes the `dev-server.js` script, so according to the error message, I think the error originates from a plugin from the script:

```
// force page reload when html-webpack-plugin template changes
compiler.plugin('compilation', function (compilation) {
  compilation.plugin('html-webpack-plugin-after-emit', function (data, cb) {
    hotMiddleware.publish({ action: 'reload' })
    cb()
  })
})
```

I wonder if .plugin syntax has deprecated and some other syntax should be used instead? I tried `compiler.hooks.done.tap({' and still not does work, it returns a 'webpack is not defined` error instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!